# Variable package name with Maven Android Plugin

Tags: android, maven, adt

I'm using the Maven Android Plugin to build my application.

Actually, I'm building 3 "branded" versions of the same app (the app icon, colors, etc... change, but not the features). I'm aware that I need to use a different package name for each application, for them to be considered as different.

So far I have managed to have "dynamic" values, using Maven filters in strings.xml :

```
<string name="app_name">${app_name}</string>
<string name="widget_name">${widget_name}</string>
<string name="app_icon">${app_icon}</string>
```

The problem is that this does not work for the package name ! If I do :

```
<manifest package="${foo.bar}">
```

ADT (well, the XML validator actually) complains saying *attribute package has invalid character '$'*

I can't find any workaround for this... Is there a way to tell ADT to launch the Maven resources filtering or something like that ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After further research, it appears to be fairly easy !

You just need to add `<renameManifestPackage>` in the configuration of the Maven Android Plugin. Seems to work starting at version > 2.9.0 :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <renameManifestPackage>${manifest_package}</renameManifestPackage>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Does it work for you? I got app that can't be installed to emulator

Comment: Man, this was answered a year and a half ago, it used to work, don't know now with latest SDK, sorry

Comment: It works! It was my misunderstanding :) Thanks for answering!