# Maven: Generating a package automatically

Tags: java, android, maven

So quick question regarding Maven and it's capability to generate different Java packages.

I'm in a scenario where I need to build multiple packages, for the same code base, with different naming conventions based on what I need at the moment.

An example of this would be.

```
package com.company.app.development
package com.company.app.test
```

Is there anyway I can do this with Maven? Again, the main problem is that I need to be able to, with Maven, dynamically change the package name as necessary.

I am doing this in an Android project currently but I am sure this applies to anything that can use Maven.

Comment: are you asking about the generation of a stub project via archetypes, or are looking for something that will modify package names and their associated directories in an ongoing project?

Comment: Modify package names ~ I may have found a solution but I am testing

Comment: Don't forget that just modifying the package declarations in the source files is not enough - you need to change the directory structure to match.

Comment: Yeah I think I found an option ... with the aapt compiler related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596771/variable-package-name-with-maven-android-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use [maven classifier](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploying-with-classifiers.html). You would deploy your jar with a `dev` and `test` classifiers. Then use [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) to refer to and build the different versions depending on your environment.

Comment: This just seems to add a file name jar, not really changing the class packages

Comment: sry, mis-read your question. I'm not sure if maven provides a way to change package names dynamically.