# Different Android Builds For Different Environments

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-build

I'd like to be able to build and install multiple versions of my app (concurrently), targeting different environments such as Development, Staging and of course Production.

The package name in the `AndroidManifest.xml` seems to be the major hurdle here, as it is what uniquely identifies the app. I thought it would be possible to simply switch between `com.mydomain.prod`, `com.mydomain.staging` and `com.mydomain.dev` or some sort of similar convention but so far I've had no luck coming up with a package structure that works for this approach.

What strategy can I employ to do this with as little pain as possible?

Comment: The package field in AndroidManifest.xml is just a unique identifier used by Google Play and doesn't need to be the same as your java source package structure.

Comment: That can't be true, can it?  If I change it, the gen folder changes and I get a ton of "R cannot be resolved to a variable" errors.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Docs: The package name serves as a unique identifier for the application. It's also the default name for the application process (see the <application> element's process process attribute) and the default task affinity of an activity (see the <activity> element's taskAffinity attribute).

Comment: Nothing to do with R, the only thing you need is to use the complete package/class name when define android components like application, activity and etc. in AndroidManifest.xml. Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596771/variable-package-name-with-maven-android-plugin/7823616#7823616) to see how easy this can be achieved by android-maven-plugin.

Comment: This worked for me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5195633/182544  I wasn't using fully qualified classpaths in my application, activity, service and receiver manifest nodes.

Answer (score 9):

With Gradle you can specify different "flavors" of your application. This is done in your `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    // …

    defaultConfig {
        // …
    }

    productFlavors {
        prod
            applicationId "com.mydomain.prod"
        }

        staging {
            applicationId "com.mydomain.staging"
        }

        dev {
            applicationId "com.mydomain.dev"
            versionCode 2
        }
    }
}
```

Each flavor properties are inherited from `defaultConfig`.

Now, in the `src` directory of your app, you can create directories with flavor-specific code/resources in it:

```
app/
|-- src/
    |-- main/
    |-- prod/
    |-- staging/
    |-- dev/
```

These links might be useful:

- [How to build customized Android application using Gradle](http://vincentbrison.com/2014/08/09/how-to-build-customized-android-application-using-gradle/)
- [Gradle Build Variants for your android project](http://tulipemoutarde.be/2013/10/06/gradle-build-variants-for-your-android-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the 'ant' build tool specificaly the 'regexp' task which can be used in order to replace text in certain files (i.e replace your app's package name in the manifest file according to the proper build target). You can also define differnet properties file for each build target (e.g 'build_development.properties' to hold all parameters relevant for building your product for development env.)... hope this is helpful..