# android-maven-plugin : update package name with <renameManifestPackage> doesn't work

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

My android project's **AndroidManifest.xml** looks like this:

```
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        <!--I want to change this package value during maven build-->
        package="com.my.app" 

        android:versionCode="2"
        android:versionName="1.2" >

       ...

    </manifest>
```

I am using **maven** to build my project. I want to update the `package` value in my `<manifest>` during build phase. I tried to use [Maven-Android-Plugin](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) to do it by declaring `<renameManifestPackage>`. My **pom.xml** :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <renameManifestPackage>com.company.app</renameManifestPackage>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

People on internet said [it is working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596771/variable-package-name-with-maven-android-plugin), but when I try above build, my `package` name is not changed after maven build. Why?